# How to make Brand not a Required Field when Creating a New Product in Admin?

Tags: product, magento2.3

How to make Brand not a Required Field when Creating a New Product in Admin? Image Below.

How would I make this not a required field?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 1.Log in to Admin Panel 
 
 2.Navigate to Stores > Attributes > Product
 
 3.Find your brand attribute and go to the Attribute Properties of your brand attribute

 4. Set the "NO" to "Values Required"
```

[image]